# subplot using for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, subplot

[image]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(num_col), figsize=(100, 30))
for j,k in enumerate(num_col):
    sb.boxplot(y = k, data=data,ax = axes[j],)
```

I made this subplot using above codes, but I want to make it more clear
I wanna see y label clearly and make more rows for subplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to make it more clear.
>   I wanna see y label clearly

For this problem you need to use [subplots.adjust](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) and ylabels fontsize

> Make more rows for subplot.

Check the modified code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sb

data = sb.load_dataset("tips")
num_col = data.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns.tolist()
rows = 2
if((((len(num_col) + 1)/rows)%rows) ==0): #when num of cols are divisable by rows
    cols = (len(num_col)+1)/rows
else:
    cols = ((len(num_col)+1)/rows) + ((len(num_col)/rows)%rows)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows,cols, figsize=(10,10))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.1, wspace=0.5)
axs = axs.ravel()
for j,k in enumerate(num_col):
    b = sb.boxplot(y = k, data=data,ax = axs[j],)
    b.set_ylabel(k,fontsize=20)
```

gives

[image]

P.S. : It is always a good practice to give a small sample of your data and full code with imports to make it reproducible.

Comment: @KenKim If you think the answer was helpful, you can officially mark it as an answer to your query.

Comment: DONE, Thanks again